# Can't display Latex expressions in pandas using Google collab

Tags: python, pandas, latex

Hello I have a problem that I cant display a simple pandas table whitch has Latex expressions in it.

- I have a simple python script:

```
    x = 1;
    x1 = 2;
    my_dict = {'Case1':{'Formula1':'$$x^{-1}$$', 'Formula2':'$$x^2$$', 'Formula3':x},
               'Case2':{'Formula1':'$$x^{-2}$$', 'Formula2':'$$x^4$$', 'Formula3':x1}}
    df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
    display(df.transpose())
```

When I am using Jupyter Notebook it works fine like this:
[Example in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k00bs.png)

but when I opened the same code in Google collab it is showing like this:

```
Formula1    Formula2    Formula3
Case1   $$x^{-1}$$  $$x^2$$ 1
Case2   $$x^{-2}$$  $$x^4$$ 2
```

Is there something I can do to make Google collab display it like Jupyter notebook ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```py
from IPython.display import Math
Math('$$x^{-1}$$')
```

This wouldn't work for the cells inside the table, but I don't think there's any way to override pandas' behavior, so you might have to write your own code to print the table out with the formulas intact.

You could also do

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Markdown

v = pd.DataFrame({'Case1':{'Formula1':'$$x^{-1}$$', 'Formula2':'$$x^2$$', 'Formula3':1},
               'Case2':{'Formula1':'$$x^{-2}$$', 'Formula2':'$$x^4$$', 'Formula3':2}})

display(Markdown(str(v)))
```

but the table formatting is broken.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am trying to find some way that makes the expressions work in the table. Jupyter notebook works well and shows the expressions in pandas. Google-Collab may have some differences. I always thought that they are the same and fully compatible...

Comment: ```python3
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Markdown

v = pd.DataFrame({'Case1':{'Formula1':'$$x^{-1}$$', 'Formula2':'$$x^2$$', 'Formula3':1},
               'Case2':{'Formula1':'$$x^{-2}$$', 'Formula2':'$$x^4$$', 'Formula3':2}})
display(Markdown(str(v)))
```
marginally works, but the formatting gets all messed up.

Comment: Yeah now it shows, I am just trying to format the table back to its original shape. But I am kinda scared, that this way wont work.

Comment: I somehow worked arount the formatting and now I am stuck at this point.          
`v = pd.DataFrame({'Case1':{'Formula1':'$x^{-1}$', 'Formula2':'$x^2$', 'Formula3':1},`  
               `'Case2':{'Formula1':'$x^{-2}$', 'Formula2':'$x^4$', 'Formula3':2}})` 

`display(Markdown(str(v.transpose())))`